# How to implement Amazon MWS api in MVC Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, amazon-mws

I am new to Amazon marketplace web service (MWS). I have read documentation of web service but I am unable to understand which api suit for update quantity and price of single or multiple product at one time.

Here is link that I am reading so far and don't know where to start.(http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_SubmitFeed.html)

Can you guys suggest me where to start?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [feed types](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_FeedType.html#FeedType_Enumeration__ProductInventoryFeeds). You're going to want to submit a pricing or inventory feed to update your inventory.  Once you have a feed created, you submit that using the [SubmitFeed](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_SubmitFeed.html) operation.

For an overview on how feeds works, check out this [What you should know about the Amazon MWS Feeds API section](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_Overview.html).

Specifically for ASP.NET, there is an [SDK](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/147-2528108-1340413?ie=UTF8&group=bde&section=feeds&version=latest) built that will help you greatly.  If you want to know how to implement that as a web api, that's another topic, but you can wrap code from the SDK inside a web api endpoint.  But start with understanding MWS.

Comment: +1 for feed types. Thanks for sharing your knowledge this could be helpful. One more question I want to ask you **Can I use MWS dll in my web api project**

Comment: @SunnyKunal sure, I do!